# AS3 Altering variable within movieclip's parent

Tags: actionscript-3, typeerror

I am trying to alter a variable within the parent or root of a movieclip with:

```
this(root).variable
```

So far I've only encountered errors, and I'm not sure how to fix them. The variable is on the stage.

The current error is:

> TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert flash.display::Stage@28b7ef99 to flash.display.MovieClip.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?
It seems like that works for everyone else.

Comment: Any help or leads would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean :

```
this.root.variable
```

or

```
this.parent.variable
```

Comment: That actually gives me an immediate error instead of a type error. The error is: Symbol 'Drone', Layer 'Layer 1', Frame 1, Line 53 1119: Access of possibly undefined property Life through a reference with static type flash.display:DisplayObject.

Comment: You might need to cast the parent to the class you have.
var yourClass:YourClass = this.parent as YourClass;
if(yourClass)
    yourClass.variable = 5;

Comment: That still gives the error, and when traced, is the same as this(root).

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Movieclip(parent).variable
```